# Add/delete rows dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a requirement adding/deleting table rows dynamically using jquery.

I have a table row with 2 text boxes and 2 buttons, one button is add and other button is delete.

whenever I click the  add button next row should be created with 2 text boxes and 2 buttons( add/delete) using Jquery.

Any suggestions around would be more appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Pretty easy. You can use the event handlers (eg: onClick()) and append a row to the table. Similarly, you can get the last child(DOM) among the rows and remove it. Where exactly are you stuck? can you add an example? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/AWM44/

```
<html>
    <body>
        <table id="foo" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Hello</td>
                <td><input type="text></td>
                    <td><input type="text></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="addButton" value="add"/></td>
                <td><input type="button" class="deleteButton" value="delete"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>

$(function(){
    $(".addButton").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").clone(true).appendTo("#foo");
    });

    $(".deleteButton").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a simple way to detect that only 1 row remains, to stop a "delete" action?  A simple counter would seem to work, but wasn't sure if there was another fancier way.

Comment: You could check how many rows are in the table by doing this: `$(this).closest("tbody").find("tr").length`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#theTable').delegate('.delete', 'click', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
})
.delegate('.add', 'click', function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').clone().appendTo( $(this).closest('tbody') );
});
```

If you don't have a `tbody`, and your `td`s are all directly under your `table`, change it to `$(this).closest('tr').clone().appendTo( $(this).closest('table') );`.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ke5Ss/

---

This can be further optimized by caching some of those selectors, but it should get you started in the right direction...

Comment: @user948030 - If an answer has solved your problem, accept it by clicking on the checkmark next to it, so that others coming to this post will know that it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = data;
var rows = [
    {
        id: 1,
        cat: 'Category',
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        cat: 'Category',
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        cat: 'Category',
    },
];

function data() {
    var html = '<tbody>';
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        const tempid = i + 1;
        html += '<tr>';
        html += "<td class='text-secondary'>" + '&equiv;' + '</td>';
        html += '<td>' + rows[i].cat + ' ' + tempid + '</td>';
        html +=
            '<td>' +
            '<span class="badge badge-success">' +
            tempid +
            '</span>' +
            '</td>';
        html +=
            "<td class='text-right'>" +
            "<button id='" +
            i +
            "' class='btn btn-danger button btn-circle text-danger bg-transparent'>X</button>" +
            '</td>';
        html += '</tr>'
    }
    html += '</tbody>';
    document.getElementById('table_rows').innerHTML = html
}

function addRow() {
    const table = document.getElementById('table_rows');
    const table_len = table.rows.length + 1;
    var html = '<tr>';
    html += "<td class='text-secondary'>" + '&equiv;' + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + '<input type="text" id="new_cat"/>' + '</td>';
    html +=
        '<td>' +
        '<span class="badge badge-success">' +
        table_len +
        '</span>' +
        '</td>';
    html +=
        "<td class='text-right'>" +
        "<input type='button' class='btn button btn-link text-primary' onclick='saveRow()' value='Save'>" +
        '</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    var newRow = document.getElementById('table_rows').insertRow();
    newRow.innerHTML = html
}

$('table').on('click', 'tr td .button', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this)
        .closest('tr')
        .remove()
});

function saveRow() {
    const new_cat = document.getElementById('new_cat').value;
    if (new_cat === '') {
        alert('Please enter some value')
    } else {
        const table = document.getElementById('table_rows');
        const id = table.rows.length;
        const table_len = table.rows.length - 1;
        table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML =
            "<tr id='row" +
            table_len +
            "'>" +
            "<td id='new_row_id" +
            table_len +
            "' class='text-secondary'>" +
            '&equiv;' +
            '</td>' +
            "<td id='cat_row" +
            table_len +
            "' class='text-secondary'>" +
            new_cat +
            '</td>' +
            "<td id='seq_row" +
            table_len +
            "'>" +
            '<span class="badge badge-success">' +
            id +
            '</span>' +
            '</td>' +
            "<td class='text-right'><input type='button' value='X' class='btn button btn-danger btn-circle text-danger bg-transparent'></td></tr>";
        $('tbody tr:last').remove()
    }
}
```